# codeigniter allow special characters (like: ä, é, î, ø, ù) in uri

Tags: codeigniter, character, uri

how to allow special characters (like: ä, é, î, ø, ù) in uri in codeigniter

Answer (score 6):

You cannot use special characters directly in URL's.

RFC 1738 contains the following paragraph:

> *URLs are written only with the graphic
>   printable characters of the US-ASCII
>   coded character set.*

A list of characters in the US-ASCII character set can be found at http://www.columbia.edu/kermit/ascii.html.

Additionally, certain characters within that set are also reserved for certain purposes for example the "=" and "&" characters. These characters (and characters not included in the US-ASCII character set) must be encoded with the use of a % sign followed by the character reference.

You can encode these values within codeigniter using urlencode(). For example if you redirected a user using redirect(urlencode(http://test.com/ä)), they would be redirected to http://test.com/%E4 which is a valid URL.

To decode this percent code back into a normal character for display on your page, simply use urldecode() for example:

```
echo 'The character is: ' . urldecode($this->uri->segment(2));
```

I hope this helps.

Dan

Answer (score 3):

You can configure this in your application/config folder, in the config.php file:

`$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-';`

Comment: i already tried for: 


$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-ø';


http://tld/assets/images/profiles/SøkerDeg.jpg


but it still returned:


An Error Was Encountered


The URI you submitted has disallowed characters.